# Passing a Email Address To a 3rd Party Website

Tags: url, variables, parameters

We have an internal website which has lots of links to 3rd party websites.  One of the major requests is to have the logged in users email passed to the 3rd Party Site once the link is click and populate the email field i.e. on a login page.  We are using IE6 which does not save passwords or saves cookies.

Is there any javascript out there that will find a id on a page and populate it by click on a link.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) can do that quite easily:

```
$('a#special_link_thing').click(function()
{
  $('#other_element').val('foo@bar.com');
});
```

---

Whoops, wrong code. You can't request content from an external page unless it is on the same domain as the JS file. You *could* create a PHP wrapper which accepts a URL and returns it's source code:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

Now, if you do AJAX, just call `wrapper.php?url=http://www.google.com/`, and you can do it with JS.

Comment: Not if `'#other_element` is on site B.